# Creating Polygons of specific sizes

Tags: qgis, polygon-creation, grids-graticules, qgis-2.10

I am very confused! I have tried this afternoon to create a polygon of a set size, namely 30m x 1.8m. I need 33 of these set over a grid (which I have created on a vector layer).

I've read everything I can on the forum and tried and failed to use several plugins to do it (e.g. ArcheoCAD, CadDigitize, CADTools) and and now very confused! Some plugins that were mentioned appear to be old and I can't find them (ImprovedPoly? and CADInput). I am running Pisa on a Windows 8 system.

I do not have co-ordinates for the polygons as they are trenches which I simply need to lay on my vector layer a N-S, E-W basis and I was going to use my grid to help me do this.

I have to draw trench plans like this a lot and I am sure there is a very simple way I can do this in QGIS - I have done similar things in CAD.

Comment: Could you not create another grid with those parameters you mentioned (X = 30m; Y = 1.8m) then run the **Dissolve** tool? This should give you a rectangular polygon of a set size. You can then _copy/paste_ this polygon into your grid layer and _move/rotate_ the feature to fit. (I would upvote but reached the limit!).

Comment: I will give this a try, in the end I ran CADInput even though its no longer supported.